# Signed overflow detection on 8080

Tags: assembly, integer-overflow, intel-8080

I want to branch if `x-y` overflows.

I came up with idea to store ***x-y*** into ***register A*** , store ***0*** into ***register B*** and ***compare*** these two registers.

Unlike 8086, [8080 doesn't have an OF flag or `jo` / `jno` instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080#Flags).

```
x db
y db

    lda x
    mov b,a
    lda y
    sub b
    mvi b,0
    cmp b
    jp overflow

notOverFlow HLT
overflow HLT
```

It works with ***x=128 , y=127*** but not with values ***x=0, y=0***.

Comment: Does 8080 have an overflow flag that `sub` sets?  8086 has an `OF` flag for signed overflow (and a CF flag for unsigned wraparound), so you can just `sub` / `jo overflow`  (i.e. just do it and jump if it *did* overflow.  You can always `add b` to undo in the `overflow` code path).  See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt for more details about what overflow and carry actually are.

Comment: Oh, you mean you can't use `jo` because 8080 doesn't have a `jo` instruction or an OF flag.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080#Flags.  That would have been clearer.

Comment: I assume you want signed arithmetic, since for unsigned `CF` works already.  Emulating `OF` yourself based on the sign bits of `x`, `y` and the result is not terribly difficult. Subtracting operands with same sign can not overflow and otherwise the result should have the same sign as `x`. `OF = X7 & !Y7 & !R7 | !X7 & Y7 & R7`

Comment: The Z80 uses the P bit to signify overflow for ALU instructions... but the 8080 doesn't; it's one place where the Z80 isn't backwards-compatible. Instead the P bit signifies parity, which is nigh-useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I efficiently do signed comparisons on the 8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639771/how-do-i-efficiently-do-signed-comparisons-on-the-8080)

Answer (score 1):

If no overflow means the arithmetic result is representable as an 8-bit signed value, then the following rules should apply:

- if `y = 0`, then no overflow.
- if `y > 0`, then overflow if `truncate(x - y) > x`.
- if `y < 0`, then overflow if `truncate(x - y) < x`.

Here `truncate(x)` means the truncated 8-bit signed value of `x`.

Then the code may look like this:

```
    lda y       ; Load y.
    mov b, a

    lda x       ; Load x.
    mov c, a

    sub b       ; No overflow if truncate(x - y) = x, that is, y = 0.
    cmp c
    jz no_overflow

    jm else     ; Jump if truncate(x - y) < x.

                ; At this point y != 0 and truncate(x - y) > x.

    mov a, b    ; Overflow if y > 0.
    ana a
    jp overflow

no_overflow:
    ...

                ; At this point y != 0 and truncate(x - y) < x.
else:
    mov a, b    ; Overflow if y < 0.
    ana a
    jp no_overflow

overflow:
    ...
```

As an optimization measure, the two `mov a, b` instructions can be replaced with a single `mov a, b` just before `jm else`.